# Partial Least Squares Implementation for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, statistics

Does anyone know of an open-source implementation of a [partial least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression) algorithm in C or C++?

Comment: I added an answer in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467321/partial-least-squares-library/14519622#14519622

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked out [R-Project](http://www.r-project.org/)?  Got to love [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+statistics) :)

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to avoid learning R :)