# Partial Least Squares Library

Tags: c++, c, statistics, regression, least-squares

There was already a question like this, but it was not answered, so I try to post it again. Does anyone know of an open-source implementation of a [partial least squares algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression) in C++ (or C)?
Or maybe a library that does it?

Answer (score 7):

1. [FastPLS](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~balajiv/FastPLS.htm) is a library that provides a C/C++ and MATLAB interface
   for  speeding up partial least squares. Its author is Balaji Vasan
   Srinivasan.   The author worked under the supervision of Professor
   Ramani Duraiswami at  the University of Maryland, College Park, MD,
   USA.
2. [Partial Least Squares and Generalized Partial Least Squares models based on NIPALS algorithm](http://code.google.com/p/plstools/downloads/list).
3. implement by yourself using [matrix libraries](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-matrix/index.html) such as [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)
4. [PLSNiplas](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~william/softwares.html#PLSNipals), [opencv](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) is required.

Comment: Suggestion #2 (plstools) appears to be for R, not C or C++.

Comment: @Pukku from the c code wrapper:  
Title: pls.c
 Description: C engine for pls computation based on NIPAS algorithm
 Author: Pierre BADY <pierre.bady@free.fr>

Comment: Ok, found it now when checking out the project from Subversion. Apparently this file was not included in the offered v1.0-6 zip archive, so I did not think it would exist.

Comment: Or use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) instead of Armadilo. I find it faster and better.

Answer (score 4):

Found the [PLS NIPALS C++](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~william/softwares.html) library, but haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 3):

[MTK++](http://mtkpp.martinpeters.ie/) is a library for drug design.

It's builds upon various matrix based libraries such as:

> The Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms (BLAS), Linear Algebra PACKage
>   (LAPACK), Boost, eigen, Qt, tinyxml and xerces-c libraries

It has a [partial least squares component](http://mtkpp.martinpeters.ie/classMTKpp_1_1pls.html).

It is open-source but the source isn't hosted on-line. You have to [contact the author](http://mtkpp.martinpeters.ie/installation.html#download)  to get it.

Answer (score 1):

found this one here:
https://github.com/tjhladish/PLS

it is c++ and using the Eigen lib